# Pygame: Cell Physics

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a dumbed down version of [agar.io](http://agar.io).

Currently, the cell is placed upon a grid background like in the game. The cell eats food, but only a smaller square section inside the circle actually eats the food (in my program), which is noticeable when you are big enough. Also, when you press the spacebar, it would split the cell into 2 smaller parts, which after a few seconds would merge back. This would require a `KEY_UP` and `K_SPACE` event, but I am not sure how to implement that. Also, once you are around a mass of 34, you can press w to shoot a tiny bit of yourself, a smaller cell at around 14 set mass.

I attempted to slow down the cell once it reaches a certain mass with a bunch of if statements. In the game, it slows down naturally. [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/3ae9vs/math_to_eat_or_not_to_eat/) and [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/34x2fa/game_mechanics_explained_in_depth_numbers_and/) are sources depicting the math used in the game.

Here is the code I have:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
width = 800
height = 600
thesurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('')

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 36)

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
size = 10
playercolor = BLUE
# set up the player and food data structure
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 35
FOODSIZE = 10
player = pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, (60, 250), 40)
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

# set up movement variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 10

score = 0
# run the game loop
while True:
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, height - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, width - player.width)

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0], event.pos[1], FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))
    if 100>score>50:
        MOVESPEED = 9
    elif 150>score>100:
        MOVESPEED = 8
    elif 250>score>150:
        MOVESPEED = 6
    elif 400>score>250:
        MOVESPEED = 5
    elif 600>score>400:
        MOVESPEED = 3
    elif 800>score>600:
        MOVESPEED = 2
    elif score>800:
        MOVESPEED = 1
    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < height:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < width:
        player.right += MOVESPEED
    thesurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    # draw the player onto the surface
    pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, player.center, size)

    # check if the player has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            size+=1
            score+=1

    # draw the food
    for i in range(len(foods)):
        pygame.draw.rect(thesurface, GREEN, foods[i])

    printscore = basicFont.render("Score: %d" % score, True, (0,0,0))
    thesurface.blit(printscore, (495, 10))

    pygame.display.update()
    # draw the window onto the thesurface
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(80)
```

Once again, here are the issues I want to solve.

- I want the cell to split into 2 parts when the spacebar is pressed. This can happen only if the cell is above 30 size.
- I want the cell to spit out a fraction of itself when you press W. The part that is spit out will be a set 15 mass. The original cell will be 15 smaller. Hitting W multiple times will allow multiple small balls to be spit out, until the original cell's mass is 20, in which case it isn't viable to spit out any more.

Edit: I have tried doing the splitting thing:

```
if event.key == K_SPACE:
    pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx,player.centery),int(size/2))
    pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx+size,player.centery+size),int(size/2))
```

After putting the above code in, and running the program and pressing the spacebar, nothing happens. The program acts like I never pressed it.

Comment: You'll do better here if you attempt solutions and ask specific questions about your code and results.  Five bullet points are far too many for a single question.

Comment: Your edit is a good start; now please extend it to say what you expected to happen, and what actually happens. "doesn't seem to work" doesn't go very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move the `.draw` call to after the call to blit your background else it will cover your player's circle.  I use a boolean flag here which you could then use with a timer to toggle whenever you want the split to turn off:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
width = 800
height = 600
thesurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('')

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 36)

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
size = 10
playercolor = BLUE
# set up the player and food data structure
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 35
FOODSIZE = 10
splitting = False
player = pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, (60, 250), 40)
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

# set up movement variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 10

score = 0
# run the game loop
while True:
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
            if event.key == K_SPACE and size >= 30: # XXX if size and space set splitting to true
                splitting = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, height - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, width - player.width)

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0], event.pos[1], FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))
    if 100>score>50:
        MOVESPEED = 9
    elif 150>score>100:
        MOVESPEED = 8
    elif 250>score>150:
        MOVESPEED = 6
    elif 400>score>250:
        MOVESPEED = 5
    elif 600>score>400:
        MOVESPEED = 3
    elif 800>score>600:
        MOVESPEED = 2
    elif score>800:
        MOVESPEED = 1
    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < height:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < width:
        player.right += MOVESPEED
    thesurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    # draw the player onto the surface
    if not splitting: # XXX check the split flag and draw accordingly...
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, player.center, size)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx,player.centery),int(size/2))
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx+size,player.centery+size),int(size/2))
    # check if the player has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            size+=1
            score+=1

    # draw the food
    for i in range(len(foods)):
        pygame.draw.rect(thesurface, GREEN, foods[i])

    printscore = basicFont.render("Score: %d" % score, True, (0,0,0))
    thesurface.blit(printscore, (495, 10))

    pygame.display.update()
    # draw the window onto the thesurface
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(80)
```

You will definitely want to make this into a few functions and/or classes too.

Comment: thank you so much! but the second one doesn't catch food.