# Pygame: Cell merging back together

Tags: python, pygame

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948724/pygame-cell-physics), I wanted to figure out how to split the cell, by pressing the space bar. I now want to know how to make them merge together by itself, suppose after 30 seconds. the newly merged cell combines the mass of the other two cells.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
width = 800
height = 600
thesurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('')

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")


basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 36)

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
playercolor = BLUE
# set up the player and food data structure
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 20
FOODSIZE = 10
splitting = False
player = pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, (60, 250), 40)
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

# set up movement variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 10
size = 10
score = size


# run the game loop
while True:
    thesurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
            if event.key == K_SPACE and size >= 32: # XXX if size and space set splitting to true
                splitting = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, height - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, width - player.width)

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0], event.pos[1], FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))
    if 100>score>50:
        MOVESPEED = 9
    elif 150>score>100:
        MOVESPEED = 8
    elif 250>score>150:
        MOVESPEED = 6
    elif 400>score>250:
        MOVESPEED = 5
    elif 600>score>400:
        MOVESPEED = 3
    elif 800>score>600:
        MOVESPEED = 2
    elif score>800:
        MOVESPEED = 1
    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < height:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < width:
        player.right += MOVESPEED

    # draw the player onto the surface
    if not splitting:
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, player.center, size)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx,player.centery),int(size/2))
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx+size,player.centery+size),int(size/2))
    # check if the player has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            size+=1

    # draw the food
    for i in range(len(foods)):
        pygame.draw.rect(thesurface, GREEN, foods[i])

    printscore = basicFont.render("Score: %d" % size, True, (0,0,0))
    thesurface.blit(printscore, (10, 550))

    pygame.display.update()
    # draw the window onto the thesurface
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(80)
```

I think this involves deleting the two circles and adding one, but I'm not sure how to move forward with it, since the program seems fragile right now.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agar.io type game?

Try creating a new timer thread.

```
import time,threading
go = False
def timer(): # pause for 30 seconds, then change "go" to true.
    global go
    time.sleep(30)
    go = True
```

Then use `threading.Thread(target=timer).start()` to start timer. After that, check every game tick to see if `go` is True, which means that the 30 second timer is up. Sorry if this was confusing. I can't explain stuff well.